# Rails - ActsAsTaggableOn gem - tagging for more models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, acts-as-taggable-on

I am playing with the awesome [ActsAsTaggableOn](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem and now I am facing with the question, how to have more than one `tagged` "systems" in one app.

For example, currently I am using already tagging for my articles - I stepted by the tutorial on GitHub and the gem created the tables **taggings** and **tags**.

How can I add tagging also for photos (I would like to have separate tables for photo-tags)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gem really doesn't support separate tables for tags on different sorts of taggables, but there's really no reason to do that that I can think of. It has one taggings table and one tags table, but taggings is polymorphic, so all you need to do is add `acts_as_taggable` to your Photo class.

If you need to fetch some info about taggings only on one type, you can add some conditions to the relevant query - `.where('taggings.taggable_type = ?', 'Photo')`, or similar.